# Check if I can connect to default maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

I need to connect to default maven repository through m2e plugin. I have modified the proxy settings in settings.xml and the network connections in
                                Preferences -> General

However when I open eclipse, I get

```
unable to update index for central http //repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

error and the artifacts are not downloaded. I doubt that there could be a problem with proxy settings. How will I be able to validate the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest verifying that the command line maven can access maven central first.

Comment: Could you please give the maven goal for checking access t maven central from command line

Comment: There is no command.  But if your project declares a dependency on an artifact that is only available in maven central, and you run mvn install ( or anything lifecycle phase really ) it will either successfully find central and get the dependency, or it will fail and tell you about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the maven project :

Go in the Package explorer view and then select your maven project, after that press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. When update poject window will open up, confirm with OK .